# DocuSign Implementation with my application

Tags: web-services, web, docusignapi

I want to integrate DocuSign with my application. There is no recipient.

The user who is signing in my application should sign the document which is generated through my application.  After signing the documents through DocuSign, the user should be returned back to my application.

I don't want any email authentication.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, no problem! Use the embedded signing option. See the [recipe](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/).

This enables your app to provide the following flow:

1. The user logs in to your app
2. Your app logs into DocuSign using an admin login for your DocuSign account. The login is done from your app to DocuSign. Your app's user does not login to DocuSign.
3. Create the pdf (or other file type)
4. Your app sends it to DocuSign using embedded signing. Your app receives back a specific url to enable the user to sign.
5. Re-direct user's browser to DocuSign by using the specific url.
6. User signs
7. User's browser is re-directed back to your app
8. Your app can download the signed document if you wish

Also: Mobile devices are fully supported, including signing via the touch screen. Do not use an iFrame if your users will use mobile devices.

Comment: See updated answer. Your app uses an admin userID and password